# Printing Values from JSON

Tags: python, json, boto3

Python Noob Here. I have a list that returns items like this:

```
"Users": [
    {
        "UserName": "Adele",
        "Path": "/",
        "CreateDate": "2013-03-07T05:14:48Z",
        "UserId": "AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Adele"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Bob",
        "Path": "/",
        "CreateDate": "2012-09-21T23:03:13Z",
        "UserId": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Bob"
    }
]
```

I want to be able to loop through the json object and print the UserNames of users whos 'CreateDate' is today:

```
    for Users, UserName in users.items():
    print Users['CreateDate']
    if Users['CreateDate'] == datetime.today():
        print Users['UserName']
```

I'm getting an error:

```
"errorType": "TypeError",

"errorMessage": "string indices must be integers"
```

Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: wait. Is the entirety of the first blurb a list?

Comment: If it is a list, that's not how you declare a list in python

Comment: It could be the value of the list/dict/str

Comment: My suggestion would be to check the data structure of Users by printing it. It's probably not a dictionary as you expected.

Comment: This is not JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is one of the many methods:

```
    import boto3
    import datetime
    a=boto3.client('iam')
    b=a.list_users()
    for i in b['Users']:
        x=i['CreateDate'].date()
        y=datetime.datetime.now().date()
        if x==y:
            print i['UserName']
```

Comment: This is a great option seems to work right, but I changed out the now() method for today:

`        x=i['CreateDate'].date().today()
        y=datetime.datetime.today().date()`

And it printed out everyone

Comment: Also to clarify they were not all created today. They were created in the past few years.

Comment: @user2019182 Ok So why exactly did u add `x=i['CreateDate'].date().today()` Can you please explain what you are trying to do with that line? `'CreateDate'` is in the datetime format so in order to consider the date alone I added the `.date()` method.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated in the comments.  Your users data structure is a list which you simply literate over with a regular forloop.

```
>>> users = {"Users": [
...     {
...         "UserName": "Adele",
...         "Path": "/",
...         "CreateDate": "2013-03-07T05:14:48Z",
...         "UserId": "AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE",
...         "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Adele"
...     },
...     {
...         "UserName": "Bob",
...         "Path": "/",
...         "CreateDate": "2012-09-21T23:03:13Z",
...         "UserId": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
...         "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Bob"
...     }
... ]}
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> today = datetime.now()
>>> for user in users['Users']:
...     user_created = datetime.strptime(user['CreateDate'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
...     if user_created.year == today.year and user_created.month == 
today.month and user_created.day == today.day:
...             print(user['UserName'])
... 
>>>
```